# Is this an appropriate username?

Tags: discussion, moderation, user-accounts

One of the top users for [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) has a username like

```
[username]--Is RBG Dead Yet
```

Presumably in reference to Supreme Court Justice Ruth Bader Ginsburg.

I don't feel feel a username like "is (person) dead yet" (replace *person* with anyone famous) is appropriate, although I'm not sure it's in direct violation of the code of conduct or acceptable use policy.

Edit: I don't mean *just* famous people. I mean it's not appropriate for anyone, but, by way of example, replace *person* with any other well-known person and ask yourself if that's ok.

Comment: Had never realised this hadn't you pointed it out. Perhaps include a search link for notability of even this acronym https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+RBG+Dead+Yet I would have thought it too cryptic, but seems to 'be a thing'? So that's clearly not you making this up/reading sth into the acronym.

Comment: I have to admit, I was wondering what that stood for.

Comment: My first thoughts were that it stood for the color spectrum of monitors (usually the _RGB_ colorspace).  But then, knowing the user in question's opinions, I was able to guess who he meant.

Comment: What user was it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I agree the display name was in very poor taste and obviously intended to troll and/or offend people on the site. I reverted it to the user's previous one.

Comment: Having a few doubts, but: Don't disagree with a single bit of this answer. However: given the current climate on MSE/SE inc: as a whole, I'd like to know, was the user informed of this censorship and told about specifically what was perceived as "'you did *this* wrong'"? AFAIK such things are pretty much in flux now from "tradition:OK" to "no, it's not!" are growing into quicksand on the network. Even suboptimal rules may be abided, but intransparent ones without feedback are unlikely to be.I'd prefer you update your A to an effect so it enables you to delete this #NLN without any doubts.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Yes, the user was informed.

Answer (score 17):

It's obviously inappropriate, and the user in question should be forced to remove the reference *at minimum*. Aside from being obviously offensive given the implication that the user is awaiting her death with glee, it's likely designed simply to troll democrats on the site.

Comment: Obviously? It's not obvious to me, and I'm even a democrat. They're doing nothing wrong and shouldn't be "forced" to do anything. It's not our job to police others' thoughts and personal expression.. especially on the internet.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica on the contrary, this is a community moderated site. It literally **is** our job to police users expressions to maintain a particular standard, and that's what we're doing here. When a user, as in this case, makes a blatant attempt to troll other users by being offensive then it's entirely reasonable to compel them to change it. There is no different between revising the offending username and deleting an offensive post.

Comment: That's certainly your opinion! Not everyone in the community agrees or cares about this. It's true.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica naturally, that's why we have the voting and Meta and whatnot. This is an example of things working as intended.