# Do we allow avatars that feature well-known politicians?

Tags: discussion, moderation, user-accounts, activism, avatar

See title. There's currently a user (who I won't name) that uses an avatar with such an image, and I'm wondering if that's allowed. Intuitively I'd have guessed no (or one can create an avatar with [insert famous politician] and "Vote for me!" on top of it), but the user has used the avatar for several days and nothing has happened.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be allowed?

Comment: @F1Krazy So "push avatars" should be allowed? You sure?

Comment: My understanding is that profiles - including images - have much more lax standards than questions and answers regarding what can be in them. There was one particular user I can recall whose bio literally just said "fuck trump" and that was perfectly okay. So if that's allowed, I don't see why (for example) someone wouldn't be allowed to have a "Vote Trump" avatar.

Comment: @F1Krazy then this question is resolved if a mod confirms that it's indeed allowed. I imagine we'll sooner or later start seeing avatars with "Stop Gaza genocide" or something like that.

Comment: Well, we already have Evan Carroll and his BDS avatar, which he's had for years and isn't too far removed from a "Stop Gaza genocide" avatar...

Comment: [Extremely related](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/are-activist-usernames-allowed-on-this-website). I did it in part to test a theory someone advanced there. By the way, I can't voluntarily change it back until March 22 or so. (only 1 change/month allowed, apparently.) Mods could reset it earlier though.

Comment: @Allure what do you mean by a push avatar?

Comment: @JoeW Which part of that phrase do you not understand?

Comment: @Allure The phrase isn't the issue, it is when you say push avatar what exactly do you mean? How does an avatar become a push avatar.

Comment: @JoeW like when you take this image and use it as your avatar: https://twitter.com/USCPR_/status/1712812150140379540

Comment: @Allure People seem to be using that as a username with no issue and I don't see how using it as an avatar is any different.

Comment: @JoeW then write that as an answer.

Comment: @Allure Disagreeing with you on a single example doesn't make for a good answer.

Comment: @JoeW I didn't even express an opinion. This is not the first time you've heard things I didn't say. Just FYI.

Comment: @Allure I asked for an example of a push avatar, you responded with an example, i pointed out that your example is being used as an username and if that use isn’t considered a push username and is acceptable using it as an avatar is also acceptable. You can’t claim you didn’t express an opinion when saying something is a push avatar.

Comment: @JoeW at no point did I say push avatars are unacceptable.

Comment: @Allure that is how I read your comment asking if they should be allowed.

Comment: @JoeW then you read it wrong. Not sure what else there is to say.